# parse xml files block by block and get the values inside each block

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a 10 GB xml file which include list of different blocks. Here is a snippet of my file:

```
<image>
    <ref>www.test.com</ref>
    <label/>
    <number>0</number>
    <ID>ID0</ID>
    <name>test1</name>
    <comment>
        <line number="0">This is a comment</line>
        <line number="1">This is also another comment</line>
    </comment>
    <creationDate>2017-02-13T15:46:16-04:00</creationDate>
</image>

<result>
    <ref>www.test1.com</ref>
    <label/>
    <number>001</number>
    <ID>RE1</ID>
    <name>test2</name>
    <comment>
        <line number="0">This is a comment2</line>
    </comment>
    <creationDate>2017-01-13T15:46:16-04:00</creationDate>
</result>

<image>
    <ref>www.test3.com</ref>
    <label/>
    <number>1</number>
    <ID>ID1</ID>
    <value>10030</value>
    <name>test3</name>
    <comment>
        <line number="0">This is a comment3</line>
    </comment>
    <creationDate>2017-04-13T15:46:16-04:00</creationDate>
</image>
```

So my goal is using *iterparse* of *celementtree* to parse my file in  serialize mode but want to get each block at a time. For example I like to get the whole block of *image* and then parse the values inside that block.
For example I need to get first image block (`*<image>... </image>*`) block and then print the values inside it which are **www.test.com, 0, id0, test1, this is a comment and 2017-02-13T15:46:16-04:00.**

So I used the following code but it seems it only read xml file line by line and also could not print the values inside each line or element:

```
for event, element in ET.iterparse(pathtofile):
   print element.tag , element.attrib
```

Can you help me in this problem. I am totally new in xml parsing.
I also would like to convert each parsed block to a dictionary in python. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not reading your XML file "line by line".  It *is* returning an `end` event at the end of each element.  That is, if your input file look like:

```
<data>
  <widgets location="earth">
    <widget name="gizmo"/>
    <widget name="gadget"/>
    <widget name="thingamajig"/>
  </widgets>
</data>
```

The sequence of return values from a simple call to `iterparse` would be:

```
end <Element widget at 0x7f31e3132488>
end <Element widget at 0x7f31e3123f38>
end <Element widget at 0x7f31e3123ef0>
end <Element widgets at 0x7f31e31327a0>
end <Element data at 0x7f31e31324d0>
```

If you want, you can also [receive `start` events](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm) at the *beginning* of each element, like this:

```
for event, element in etree.iterparse(fd, events=('start', 'end')):
    print event, element
```

For which the output would be:

```
start <Element data at 0x7fccf78cc518>
start <Element widgets at 0x7fccf78cc7e8>
start <Element widget at 0x7fccf78cc4d0>
end <Element widget at 0x7fccf78cc4d0>
start <Element widget at 0x7fccf78bdf80>
end <Element widget at 0x7fccf78bdf80>
start <Element widget at 0x7fccf78bdf38>
end <Element widget at 0x7fccf78bdf38>
end <Element widgets at 0x7fccf78cc7e8>
end <Element data at 0x7fccf78cc518>
```

If I wanted to build a list of `widgets` for each `location`, then I would probably want to respond to the `start` event by initializing a list, and then appending each new widget to that list until I reach the end element, as in:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('data2.xml') as fd:
    widgets = {}
    loc = None

    for event, element in etree.iterparse(fd, events=('start', 'end')):
        if event == 'start' and element.tag == 'widgets':
            loc = element.get('location')
            widgets[loc] = []
        elif event == 'end' and element.tag == 'widget':
            widgets[loc].append(element.get('name'))

    print widgets
```

The output of which is:

```
{'earth': ['gizmo', 'gadget', 'thingamajig']}
```

I hope this gives you some idea how to process each block of interest in your input file.